# Razer Lancehead TE (wired) support Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mouse, hardware

I have been trying to get my Razer Lancehead TE mouse, model number rz01-213, to work with openrazer so I can adjust the LEDs and DPI but I haven't had any luck. According to this discussion on github the razer_test branch for razergenie supports it.

https://github.com/openrazer/openrazer/issues/322
https://github.com/z3ntu/RazerGenie/tree/razer_test

But I can't figure out how to install this, I have no idea how github works. The install instructions didn't work for me since I only know how to copy-paste into the terminal. If someone could explain how to do this in simple terms i'd appreciate it.

Comment: If you have actually read what's in the git page you'd find a section telling you that there are packages already made for the most common distros including Ubuntu. Here: https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=hardware%3Arazer&package=razergenie

Comment: the packages are for the stable build which I already have installed, 0.8.1, which doesn't include my mouse, i'm trying to use the test branch. According to the posts on the issues page I need to use a meson build procedure but i can't get it to work. The first time I tried I got dependency errors, the one that is keeping me from moving is "Native dependency 'hidapi-hidraw' not found". I can't figure out how to install it.